# AndEngine Android Tower of Hanoi errors when the counting of movements reach to 10

Tags: android, andengine, towers-of-hanoi

I'm wondering as to why the code malfunctions when the move count reaches to 10. Can anybody help me determine which causes the error and how to fix it? I've been wondering since all it does is to count yet somehow it malfunctions when it reaches to 10.

```
public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {
private ITexture main_font_texture;
Text countText;
Font main_font; 
int movesCount;
Scene scene = new Scene();
private static int CAMERA_WIDTH = 800;
private static int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 480;

private ITextureRegion mBackgroundTextureRegion, mTowerTextureRegion, mRing1, mRing2, mRing3;
private Stack<Ring> mStack1, mStack2, mStack3;
private Sprite mTower1, mTower2, mTower3;

public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);
}

@Override
protected void onCreateResources() {


    try {

         main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
         main_font.load();


         BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
         main_font_texture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);


        ITexture backgroundTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/background.png");
            }
        });

        ITexture towerTexture = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {

            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/tower.png");
            }
        });

        ITexture ring1 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {

            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring1.png");
            }
        });

        ITexture ring2 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {

            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring2.png");
            }
        });
        ITexture ring3 = new BitmapTexture(this.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {

            @Override
            public InputStream open() throws IOException {
                return getAssets().open("gfx/ring3.png");
            }
        });
        backgroundTexture.load();
        towerTexture.load();
        ring1.load();
        ring2.load();
        ring3.load();

        this.mBackgroundTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(backgroundTexture);
        this.mTowerTextureRegion = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(towerTexture);
        this.mRing1 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring1);
        this.mRing2 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring2);
        this.mRing3 = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(ring3);

        this.mStack1 = new Stack<Ring>();
        this.mStack2 = new Stack<Ring>();
        this.mStack3 = new Stack<Ring>();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Debug.e(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    Sprite backgroundSprite = new Sprite(0, 0, this.mBackgroundTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    mTower1 = new Sprite(0.241f * CAMERA_WIDTH, 0.133f * CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mTower2 = new Sprite(0.5f * CAMERA_WIDTH, 0.133f * CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mTower3 = new Sprite(0.756f * CAMERA_WIDTH, 0.133f * CAMERA_HEIGHT, this.mTowerTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    Ring ring1 = new Ring(1, 139, 174, this.mRing1, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(this.getmStack().peek().getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                return false;
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    Ring ring2 = new Ring(2, 118, 212, this.mRing2, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(this.getmStack().peek().getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                return false;
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    Ring ring3 = new Ring(3, 97, 255, this.mRing3, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
            if(this.getmStack().peek().getmWeight() != this.getmWeight())
                return false;
            this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);
            if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                checkForCollisionsWithTowers(this);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    this.mStack1.add(ring3);
    this.mStack1.add(ring2);
    this.mStack1.add(ring1);

    ring1.setmStack(mStack1);
    ring2.setmStack(mStack1);
    ring3.setmStack(mStack1);
    ring1.setmTower(mTower1);
    ring2.setmTower(mTower1);
    ring3.setmTower(mTower1);

    scene.attachChild(backgroundSprite);
    scene.attachChild(mTower1);
    scene.attachChild(mTower2);
    scene.attachChild(mTower3);
    scene.attachChild(ring1);
    scene.attachChild(ring2);
    scene.attachChild(ring3);
    scene.registerTouchArea(ring1);
    scene.registerTouchArea(ring2);
    scene.registerTouchArea(ring3);

    scene.setTouchAreaBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);

     countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:" + movesCount , this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
     countText.setPosition(0,0);
     scene.attachChild(countText);

        setTheMovesCount();
    return scene;
}


private void setTheMovesCount() {


}

private void checkForCollisionsWithTowers(Ring ring) {
    Stack<Ring> stack = null;
    Sprite tower = null;

    if (ring.collidesWith(mTower1) && (mStack1.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack1.peek()).getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack1;
        tower = mTower1;
        movesCount = movesCount + 1;
        if(countText != null){
              countText.setText("Moves: "+ movesCount);
        }

    } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower2) && (mStack2.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack2.peek()).getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack2;
        tower = mTower2;
        movesCount = movesCount + 1;
        if(countText != null){
              countText.setText("Moves: "+ movesCount);
        }

    } else if (ring.collidesWith(mTower3) && (mStack3.size() == 0 || ring.getmWeight() < ((Ring) mStack3.peek()).getmWeight())) {
        stack = mStack3;
        tower = mTower3;
        movesCount = movesCount + 1;
        if(countText != null){
              countText.setText("Moves: "+ movesCount);
        }

    } else {
        stack = ring.getmStack();
        tower = ring.getmTower();


    }
    ring.getmStack().remove(ring);
    if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() == 0) {
        ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, tower.getY() + tower.getHeight() - ring.getHeight());

    } else if (stack != null && tower !=null && stack.size() > 0) {
        ring.setPosition(tower.getX() + tower.getWidth()/2 - ring.getWidth()/2, ((Ring) stack.peek()).getY() - ring.getHeight());

    }
    stack.add(ring);
    ring.setmStack(stack);
    ring.setmTower(tower);


    isGameOver();


}



private void isGameOver(){

    if(mStack3.size() == 3){

         Font main_font = FontFactory.create(this.getFontManager(), this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, BitmapTextureFormat.RGBA_8888, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA, Typeface.DEFAULT, 60, true, Color.BLACK_ABGR_PACKED_INT);
         main_font.load();

         Text gameOverText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "GameOver" , this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
         gameOverText.setPosition(CAMERA_WIDTH/2 - gameOverText.getWidth()/2, CAMERA_HEIGHT/2 - gameOverText.getHeight()/2);
         scene.attachChild(gameOverText);
         scene.clearTouchAreas();


   }
}
    }
```

Comment: whats the malfunction?

Comment: The application "Suddenly Stops" once the movement count reaches to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your constructor of 'Text'(i.e. countText ) as follows

```
 countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:" + movesCount , 10, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
     countText.setPosition(0,0);
     scene.attachChild(countText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have to set countText maximum buffer size. Change your countText initialization in the following way

```
countText = new Text(0, 0, main_font, "Moves:0123456789" , this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
countText.setText("Moves:" + movesCount");
countText.setPosition(0,0);
scene.attachChild(countText);
```